# How to delete rows which are referenced by other table using a stored procedure?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

How to create a stored procedure that checks if the row has references in another table?

Here is my code:

```
Create Procedure dbo.usp_Delete
    @type dbo.udt_Delete ReadOnly
As  
Begin Tran
    Begin Try

        DELETE FROM dbo.File 
        WHERE EXISTS (SELECT p.Id FROM dbo.Payment p 
                      WHERE pt.Id = File.Id)
```

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.  Your question is also lacking a question.  Sample data and desired results would also help.

Comment: Your `WHERE` refers to `pt.Id` but your `FROM` uses alias `p`.